# GCC output file's size seems too big

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compilation, filesize

I have the following code(file.c):

```
int main() {}
```

I go gcc file.c, and the output file `file.exe` is **26.5KB**
I also tried with `-O2`, `-Ofast`, `-Os` but the size stays the same. I have included no headers, nothing; I even tried putting `int main(void) {}`.

Shouldn't the output file be roughly **1KB**? [I am using Windows 10 - GCC 4.8.1]

---

**Context:**

I am trying to understand how PE files work in windows, and so far, I think I have a great grasp of the concept, so I wanted to run some tests because I want to be able to take code from another file, lets say `file2.exe`, and try to sneak it inside `file.exe` with **OllyDBG**. But since this pretty much NULL code yields a freaking **26.5KB**, I really dont know what to do...

Comment: **Don't** add a `--static`; you'll really freak out.

Comment: it did nothing, I guess because I didnt include any libraries

Comment: Well if you have good (or rather, exceptional) knowledge of PE files and their format, you could always try something similar to [this hack for ELF](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html). I don't recommend it other than as a curiosity though.

Comment: I will check it out, but this question (the seemingly oversized output files) has been bugging me for years now, and only now I have a practical reason to search more thorowly for an answer

Comment: By the way, if you want to "sneak" Some payload into the executable, wouldn't it be easier to detect if the original file was smaller, as it would be a (relatively) big change in size?

Comment: sneak was nor the right word, Im not trying to make it undetectable

Answer (score 0):

there are a LOT of items that get added to a file to make it executable.

In the following example, on Linux 16.04

gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

I wrote the following source in a 
file named untitled2.c

```
int main(void)
{

}
```

Then compiled it into untitled2.o

```
gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes  -c untitled2.c   -o untitled2.o -I.
```

then linked it into untitleed2

```
gcc -ggdb  -std=gnu11 -o untitled2 untitled2.o
```

Here are the results.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rkwill root      22 Mar 21 20:41 untitled2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rkwill rkwill  2608 Mar 21 20:41 untitled2.o
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rkwill rkwill 16904 Mar 21 20:41 untitled2
```

I.E. the original source file is 22 bytes.  The compiled file is 2608 bytes (no optimization parameters) the executable file is 16904 bytes

`strip`ing the file (removing the debug info) would reduce the file size slightly, but not enough to eliminate the significant difference in size.

Comment: And using `-v` in the compilation lines will tell you more about what's going on — and in particular about the extra files used in the link phase.